# bootstrapにprimary2などを作って色を足したい

Tags: sass, twitter-bootstrap

### 前置き

bootstrap（現在はv3.3.5を使用）ですが、現在sassを使って、
`$brand-primary`のような用意された変数を使い色を変更することはできました。

そこで、今度は色を追加しようと思ったのですが、`brand-success`や`brand-info`などは用意されていますが、これらの色を変更するのは、用途が違うと感じました。

### やりたいこと

`$brand-primary2`というようなものを作って
`brand-success2`, `brand-info2` といったように、`primary`に紐付いた`success`や`info`も用意したい。

例えば緑を基調にしたサブページでは`$brand-primary2`に緑を設定し、`brand-success2`にはより深い緑色を設定。

同じく赤を基調にしたサブページでは、`$brand-primary3`をつくり、、、ということを考えています。

[bootstrap-sassに色関係のクラスを追加する - Qiita](http://qiita.com/dtsuka/items/9fc4177770c5671db16c)
をみつけましたが、ものすごいコード量です。著者も書いていらっしゃるとおりもっと良い方法はないでしょうか？　また上記は色を増やすことはできていますが、`primary`に紐付いた`success`や`info`も用意したいということとは違うように感じました。

(単純にbootstrapに色を追加するうまいやり方を解答してくださってもOKです)